# Is it necessary to write `async with AsyncClient`?

Tags: python, httpx

In the docs for `httpx.AsyncClient`, it says

> ```py
> async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
>     response = await client.get('https://example.org')
> ```

Is this necessary? Why can't I write:

```
async def get_client():
    return AsyncClient()

client = await get_client()

response = await client.get(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly use the second form without putting it inside a [`with`-block / context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18778046/2745495), but then you'll need to remember to manually call [`.aclose`](https://www.python-httpx.org/api/#asyncclient) on the client once you are done with it.

https://www.python-httpx.org/api/#asyncclient

> `aclose(self)`
>
> Close transport and proxies.

From the httpx docs on using a `Client`:
https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/#usage

> The recommended way to use a `Client` is as a context manager. **This will ensure that connections are properly cleaned up when leaving the `with` block**:
>
> ```
> with httpx.Client() as client:
>    ...
> ```

While that guidance above shows a `Client`, the same applies for an `AsyncClient`:
https://www.python-httpx.org/async/#opening-and-closing-clients

> Use `async with httpx.AsyncClient()` if you want a context-managed client.
>
> ```
> async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
>     ...
> ```

Depending on your use case, it may not be a problem for you. But if you are going to be integrating an `httpx.AsyncClient` into a larger application (ex. FastAPI), or have multiple instances of an `httpx.AsyncClient` sharing the same networking resources, or your application that use an `httpx.AsyncClient` is sharing the system with other applications that *also* use networking resources, it is good practice to make sure you call `.aclose()`. **And putting it inside a context manager helps you to do that**.

You can check out questions like this for reasons to close:
[In aiohttp or httpx do I need to close session/client on application shutdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65103017/2745495) :

> In my experience, this may not always be the case, as I remember when programming with php, I had to manually kill all the database connections, otherwise on application restart I got "The process is already using that port".

If you really don't want or can't use a context manager:

> Alternatively, use `await client.aclose()` if you want to close a client explicitly:
>
> ```
> client = httpx.AsyncClient()
> ...
> await client.aclose()
> ```